# converting double to decimal and infinity error

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013

when i run this piece of code I'm getting the input string was not in correct format when it is?

```
private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            tb4 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
            tb5 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);         
            double ans2 = tb2 / tb3;
            decimal ans3 = Convert.ToDecimal(tb2/tb3);

            label8.Text = Convert.ToString(ans3);
        }
```

plus when it does work i sometime get an infinity answer hence why i tried the decimal method so i could have a more accurate answer.

Comment: try using `Double.TryParse` to catch when the text controls contain characters other than numerals

Comment: On which line exactly? What is the value of that you want to convert? What is your `CurrentCulture`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 lines where you have an input string conversion.

```
        tb4 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox2.Text);
        tb5 = Convert.ToDouble(textBox3.Text);
```

The best bet with this type of question is to step through your code with the debugger, that is what it is for. If using Visual Studio, set a breakpoint on the first line of the method, then start debugging with F5.

It is a good practice to put individual try/catch blocks around each conversion (unless you don't need to provide that level of detail in your error messages to the user) or use Double.TryParse() instead of Convert, and check the result of each TryParse() call.

> > plus when it does work i sometime get an infinity answer hence why i tried the decimal method so i could have a more accurate answer.

You'll get a more accurate result if you convert the individual operands to Decimal before the division.

```
decimal ans3 = (decimal)tb2/(decimal)tb3;
```

Comment: thanks for this, i'm going to research on how to use the debugger

Comment: Hi do you know where i can find out how to debug in visual studio, as all te videos i have seen do not explain it thoroughly enough

Answer (score 1):

There are often times when an input string will not be registered as a correct format (such as when a user enters "Orange" into textBox2 - there's simply no way to translate that to a number). For this reason, it is often better for you to utilize test methods such as [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.double.tryparse(v=vs.110).aspx), rather than allowing code which could throw an exception.

An example of this:

```
double tb4, tb5;
if(double.TryParse(textBox2.Text, out tb4) && double.TryParse(textBox3.Text, out tb5))
{
    // Do math here, since tb4 and tb5 are valid
}
else
{
    // Well, something went wrong...
    label8.Text = "Could not parse values."
}
```

As for the coming out to infinity, we would need to know more about what data was inputted!